Can an inductor increase circuit current?
Suppose there is a simple circuit with a resistor, battery and inductor.  The question that came to me is, by opening the circuit breaker, can the inductor be used to oppose and slow down the circuit current reduction time, and in fact, by preventing the rapid and sudden drop in current, produce more current than the initial current of the circuit?  In fact, because the voltage created by the inductor is proportional to the changes in the magnetic flux divided by the changes in time, can it be possible to create more current than the initial current, by drastically reducing the changes in time? Or, is the fact that the entire inductor creates current at the same rate as the initial current?


Can an inductor increase circuit current?

The short answer is no for the situation you describe.
The inductor resists a change in current. So when the circuit breaker opens the inductor produces a very large voltage across the breaker contacts that breaks down the air causing an arc between the contacts so that current continues to flow.
The inductor doesn't produce more current. It just briefly maintains the current that existed before switching until the energy stored in the magnetic field of the inductor just prior to the breaker operating is dissipated in the air as heat by the arc as well as the series resistance.
Hope this helps.

The circuit you're searching for is called a buck converter. It cyclically switches current going from its power source into to an inductor while continuously drawing current from the other end. The average output current is thus more than the average input current.

Since you open the circuit, you don't have any current, just high voltage by breaking fast.
